# Missing Linux Kernel mitigations for 'iTLB multihit' hardware vulnerabilities

Tags: vulnerability, server, known-vulnerabilities

I don't know how to mitigate `iTLB multihit` vulnerability.

> /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit | KVM:
> Vulnerable

Found this: [iTLB multihit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html),
But i have no access to the host machine where the VM is hosted.
Is it possible to fix or mitigate this vulnerability from the guest operating system ?

> ```
> System specification: 
> Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS
> Kernel: 5.4.0-125-generic
> ```

I was trying to modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity mitigations=on"` and append `mitigations=on` but it doesn't provide any result.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html Virtualization with trusted guests¶

    If the guest comes from a trusted source, you may assume that the guest will not attempt to maliciously exploit these errata and no further action is required.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I see. We rent the private cloud so, i'm the guest and we are a trusted source, but what if the server(VM) is exposed to the internet and someone will getting unattended access ? Maybe i should ask our cloud provider to mitigate this issue by editing /sys/module/kvm/parameters/nx_huge_pages at hypervisor system.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Most mitigations incur a performance loss (some very heavy) though, so they might not be inclined to fix it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I will try to go this way and report it to cloud provider.
Thanks for help and your time. Have a good day.

Comment: I found one more approach. I will be able to check it at the beginning of the next week.
mitigations=auto,nosmt - it should enable all CPU vulnerabilities mitigation.

Comment: mitigations=auto,nosmt - unfortunately, do not mitigate the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find solution.

In my case i need to install `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04` after this step Vulnerability scanners display **0.0** points.

```
lscpu
```

showing

```
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
```

it means base at [iTLB multihit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html)

```
KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
```

KVM is not vulnerable because Virtual Machine Extensions (VMX) is not supported.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit 
KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
```